# Visibility problem with 'restricted to certain pages'

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm porting a site from D6 to D8 and having problems with block visibility for listed pages. I have a config like this which worked on D6:

```
news
news/*
```

And pages like `/news/op-ed-suu-kyis-plan-outsource-myanmars-presidency-problems-proxy` would match and display the block. In D8.1.2 I have the same rules, but the migrated page with the same URL doesn't trigger the block. If I remove the rules, the block displays again, so it's definitely something here.

Am I missing some changes in how D8 handles these rules? or is it maybe something with URL aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course! Now that Drupal 8 returns URL aliases with the leading slashes, I needed to update my rules to:

```
/news/
/news/*
```

to get it working as in D6